How do I pass xcom to 3rd party operator when using TaskFlow?
UPDATE. I realise I haven't explained the problem concisely enough so I've posted a revised question at How do I pass xcom to traditional operator from task created using @task decorator?

I am using Amazon's EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator operator. I've gotten the basic functionality working like this:
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator

create_app = EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator(
                task_id="create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless",
                job_type="SPARK",
                release_label="emr-6.9.0",
                config={...},
                executor_config=executor_config,
                aws_conn_id="",
            )

However that value passed to parameter config is sufficiently complex that I'd like to construct it in upstream tasks and pass it via xcom because:

I want to visualise as separate tasks so that my DAG visually represents the work going on
The config value will get exposed explicitly in the XCom tab in the UI
I've never used TaskFlow API before and this is a good way of getting familiar with it

Here's what I have:
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.emr import EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator

        with TaskGroup(group_id="create_emr_serverless_app") as create_emr_serverless_app_group:
            @task(task_id="network_configuration")
            def network_configuration() -> dict:
                return {
                    "subnetIds": ["subnet-ABC"],
                    "securityGroupIds": ["sg-12345"],
                }
            @task(task_id="maximum_capacity")
            def maximum_capacity() -> dict:
                return {
                    "cpu": "20vCPU",
                    "memory": "64GB",
                }
            @task(task_id="auto_stop_configuration")
            def auto_stop_configuration() -> dict:
                return {
                    "enabled": True,
                    "idleTimeoutMinutes": 15,
                }
            @task(task_id="config")
            def config(network_configuration: dict, maximum_capacity: dict, tags: dict, auto_stop_configuration: dict) -> dict:
                return {
                    "name": "my-emv-serverless-app",
                    "networkConfiguration": network_configuration,
                    "maximumCapacity": maximum_capacity,
                    "autoStopConfiguration": auto_stop_configuration,
                }
            create_slo_app = EmrServerlessCreateApplicationOperator(
                task_id="create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless",
                job_type="SPARK",
                release_label="emr-6.9.0",
                # ***** All upstream tasks being called here *****
                config=config(network_configuration(), maximum_capacity(), auto_stop_configuration()),
                executor_config=executor_config,
                aws_conn_id="",
            )

I would have expected that task config would appear upstream of create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless but that hasn't happened:

Furthermore when I execute the DAG task create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless fails with err:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/emr.py", line 535, in execute
response = self.hook.conn.create_application(
TypeError: botocore.client.ClientCreator._create_api_method.._api_call() argument after ** must be a mapping, not PlainXComArg

From that error message I assume that the correct value is not getting passed to create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless. I don't know why that is so.
Please can someone tell me how to pass the value returned from task config to the config parameter of task create_spark_app_on_emr_serverless?
note that I have verified that return_value from task config is as expected

